# How to Round DateTime in Vb.net to the nearest 5mins

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, visual-studio-2005

I am writing some data analysis software, I want to upscale timebase of my Raw Data. My Raw Data has a time step of ~2minutes. I want to scale the data into several database tables with a timestep of 5minutes, hourly, daily and monthly. I plan to run each of these from the raw data to keep my accuracy up.

The problem I am currently having is taking an initial value and finding the closest 'round' time point I want to it, to be my start point. For example, I will start with the point 13/03/12 00:01:36 as my start point, I want the code to find 13/03/12 00:00:00 as the closest time point so it will start calculating from there. For each time point I want to take half of the time step on each side. So 12/03/12 23:57:30 to 13/03/12 00:02:29 will become 13/03/12 00:00:00.

The Data is taken from Access using a SQL query and the Date and Value are stored in two side by side Arrays. Below is my code so far. It will round the values up to the NEXT 5 minutes, rather than up or down to the NEAREST 5 mimutes.

```
Private Sub RateStateScale(ByVal Parameter As Integer, ByVal Timebase As String)

    Dim NewDate(0)
    Dim NewData(0)
    Dim RecordCounter
    Dim MinValue As Date = ScaleDate(0)
    Dim startpoint As String

    For RecordCounter = 0 To ScaleDate.GetLength(0)
        If MinValue > ScaleDate(RecordCounter) Then
            MinValue = ScaleDate(RecordCounter)
        End If
    Next

    Do Until MinValue.Minute Mod 5 = 0
        MinValue = MinValue.AddMinutes(1)
    Loop



End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's try some VB, for a "round to nearest 5 minutes" function:

```
' just some date, should be a parameter to your function
Dim mydatetime = new DateTime(2012,3,12,23,57,30)

' split into date + time parts
Dim datepart = mydatetime.Date
Dim timepart = mydatetime.TimeOfDay

' round time to the nearest 5 minutes
timepart = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Math.Floor((timepart.TotalMinutes+2.5)/5.0) * 5.0)

' combine the parts
Dim newtime = datepart.Add(timepart)
' a function would return this value
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be the following:

```cs
var date = new DateTime(2012,03,12,23,57,30);
var fullFiveMinutes = date.Minute / 5;
// result will be our date rounded down to the previous full five minutes
var result = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day
                          date.Hour, fullFiveMinutes * 5, 0);

// if we add exactly 2.5 minutes to our date variable and the result represents
// another full five minutes we need to round up.
if(date.AddSeconds(2.5 * 60).Minute / 5 != fullFiveMinutes)
    result = result.AddMinutes(5);
```

This is C# code, I am sure you can translate it.

Comment: The first data point may not be at 12/03/12 23:57:30, the data will come from several different logged site starting and stopping at different times. The start pointneeds to be taken from the array, hence the loop looking for `min value`. The note in the code also says `rounded down to the previous full five minutes`, I would like the code to round up or down to the nearest five minutes.

Comment: @Pezzzz: Please simply try it. If you only saw the first comment, you didn't read the whole code. `12/03/12 23:57:30` will be rounded to `12/03/13 00:00:00`. There is no need to use anything from the array as you simply want to round to the nearest five minutes.

Comment: @Blam, When I looked at the code for the first time it was different to how it is now, there were 3 lines starting with var, a comment and then an if statement. He changed it in the edit.

Comment: @Pezzzz: Wrong. I simply changed the syntax coloring. You can see it in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12478384/revisions)

Comment: how about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147499/is-it-possible-to-view-all-of-the-edits-to-an-answer-post)

Answer (score 1):

Could you do? (very basic, but it should give an idea)

```
Dim tValue As Date = ScaleDate(0) 

'find the next highest 5 minute mark
For RecordCounter = 0 To ScaleDate.GetLength(0)              
    If tValue > ScaleDate(RecordCounter) Then                  
        tValue = ScaleDate(RecordCounter)              
    End If          
Next  

Do Until tValue.Minute Mod 5 = 0         
        tValue = tValue.AddMinutes(1)     
Loop

'compare the original value to the next highest.  If more than 2.5 minutes, then subtract 5 minutes
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, tValue, MinValue) > 150 Then
    MinValue = tValue.AddMinutes(-5)
Else
    MinValue = tValue
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a decade old, but for here is what I do.  Divide time by 5, this gives you the current units of the 5 minute compression.  The integer of this result can be used to "round down" to the prior 5 minute compression, now add in 5 minutes to get the compression time that ndate belongs in.

```
   Dim ndate As DateTime = Now
   Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime(ndate.Year, ndate.Month, ndate.Day, ndate.Hour, Fix(ndate.Minute / 5) * 5, 0).AddMinutes(5)
```